# Dynamics check form event through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, onchange, crm

In CRM Dynamics, I want to write a single JavaScript function and use it in both onChange and onSave form events since the verification code for both cases is identical, the only difference is what I do post-verification. So instead of writing two separate functions I wanted to write a single one that could check whether it was triggered on the onChange or onSave form event. Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could use the element id instead?  Since you posted no code I can't be sure what's best for you.  Assuming you pass 'this' to the function you are calling then you can check 'this.id'.  You could use a switch statement to define the case for 'onSave' and use the default case for all other uses.

Comment: Yes. Please provide some sample code

Answer (score 0):

Add a function similar to `loadMyForm` (see below) to your form, attach the onload event handler and check the *"Pass execution context as first parameter"* box.

```js
function loadMyForm(context) {
    const formContext = context.getFormContext();
    const myAttribute = formContext.getAttribute("new_myattribute");

    function isMyAttributeValid() {
        return (myAttribute.getValue() != null);
    }

    myAttribute.addOnChange(() => {
        const isValid = isMyAttributeValid();

        myAttribute.controls.forEach(c => {
            c.clearNotification();

            if (!isValid)
                c.addNotification({ messages: ["Value is not valid"], notificationLevel: "ERROR", uniqueId: '' });
        });
    });

    formContext.data.entity.addOnSave(saveContext => {
        if (!isMyAttributeValid())
            saveContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
    });
}
```